# Cointegration in error correction model with only one nonstationary variable

Tags: time-series, cointegration, ecm

I have three time series variables, two variables are stationary and one is non-stationary. Can we still search for the cointegration and use the error correction model or should I take the first difference and make the variable stationary and use another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there cannot be cointegration when only one variable is nonstationary. You need at least two variables integrated of the same degree for cointegration. In your case, you can just take the first difference of the integrated variable and proceed to modelling it along the two stationary variables. A VAR model could do.

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was searching for.